# Would a pending transaction block all subsequent transactions?

Tags: pending-transactions, nonce

I know that each ethereum transaction has a corresponding nonce, which is a positive increasing number. Say if tx1 with nonce 97 is still pending, would subsequent tx2 with nonce 98 also blocked until tx1 is processed? I haven't seen this behavior documented anywhere, but based on my personal trading experience, this seems the case - a previously blocked EtherDelta tx would block all subsequent txs, even subsequent txs are not originated from ED.

Can someone please explain a bit further? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transactions from different accounts are non-blocking, but transactions from a single account will be mined in nonce order.

More details over here: [Are Transactions originating from one account mined in nonce order?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13376/are-transactions-originating-from-one-account-mined-in-nonce-order)

Hope it helps.