# What does mining software do when two tx are sent in one block with incremented nonces, but the second tx relies on the completion of the first?

Tags: transactions, mining, erc-20, nonce

If I call `approve` and `transferFrom` on an ERC20 token in two transactions, with the nonces being 1 and 2, respectively, how do the miners know which to accept first?

Do the miners choose the ordering of the transactions? If so, does it depend on the nonce or just the `gasPrice`? If they have the same `gasPrice`, is it random which one is included first? Does mining software look at the nonce? Can a miner include a t

Looking at Etherdelta, it seems like their interface sends both transactions, [`approve`](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xcf8833869fc9064bcea86b81b206e59cec9a0b1f7456c05219c437dfd32d8037) amd [`transferFrom`](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x9ab24d06deffbf0959fce5e4fbc0894368d4b67f534bc080f601e8d9d7cc8989) in one block with an incremented Nonce. So is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transactions from a single account are mined in nonce order.

[Are Transactions originating from one account mined in nonce order?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13376/are-transactions-originating-from-one-account-mined-in-nonce-order)

Hope it helps.